# Load HBITMAP from *.bmp file in Win32 project

Tags: c++, winapi, bmp, hbitmap

Is it possible to load a *.bmp file into a HBITMAP in a Win32 project, using only WINAPI functions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using only the standard win32 library.

```
HBITMAP hBMP = (HBITMAP) LoadImage( NULL, "Your/ImagePath/a.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

`hBMP` is a handle to the `BITMAP` to use as you want.

**Note:** It is important to pass NULL as the first argument, from the docs:

> hinst [in, optional]
>
> To load a stand-alone resource (icon, cursor, or bitmap file)—for
>   example, c:\myimage.bmp—set this parameter to NULL.

From the [msdn documentation for `LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: That's an external library.

Comment: Er, by external I meant third-party libraries I guess. Will edit. Since it's a Win32 project, it already uses Winapi. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Zoidberg what are the standard libraries in Win32 projects? :S

Comment: Just one correction, hInst needs to be NULL for loading from file. I just read it in the docs. *To load a stand-alone resource (icon, cursor, or bitmap file)—for example, c:\myimage.bmp—set this parameter to NULL.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the OleLoadPictureFromPath or whatever it was called. Check it. The docs are probably still inconsistent and wrong about supported formats but in modern Windows also JPEG and PNG supported.